# How to narrow down results from web scraping using Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets

My **goal** is to scrape the website : https://www.multpl.com/s-p-500-pe-ratio

Where I specifcally want to get the SP500 PE number, that is 39.57 (at the time of writing). **I need this number as 39,57, and not 39.57.**

**This is my code:**

```
function webScraper() {

var webURL = "https://www.multpl.com/s-p-500-pe-ratio";

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(webURL);

var $ = Cheerio.load(response.getContentText()); 

var itemsOfInterest = $('.info-left').first().text().trim();


Logger.log(itemsOfInterest)

return itemsOfInterest

}
```

**The issue:**
My code works, but it gives me too much information. Basically I need to narrow it down. I also need to convert 39.57 to 39,57.

Below is all the info the code gives me:

Current
S&P 500 PE Ratio:
39.57

+0.15
(0.39%)

4:00 PM EST, Fri Feb 5

Mean:
15.88

Median:
14.84

Min:
5.31

(Dec 1917)

Max:
123.73
(May 2009)

Price to earnings ratio, based on trailing twelve month “as
reported”
earnings.
Current PE is estimated from latest reported earnings and current market
price.

Source:
Robert Shiller and his book Irrational Exuberance for historic S&P 500 PE Ratio.

See also

Shiller PE Ratio

S&P 500 Price to Book Value

S&P 500 Price to Sales Ratio

S&P 500 Earnings Yield

S&P 500 Earnings

Inflation Adjusted S&P 500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve `39.57` from the URL of `https://www.multpl.com/s-p-500-pe-ratio` and convert `39.57` to `39,57`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- When I saw the HTML data of the URL, I noticed that the number of `39.57` is included in the JSON object. I thought that when this is used, the value you expected might be able to be simply retrieved.

In this answer, as a workaround, I would like to propose to retrieve the value from the JSON object in the HTML data. When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function webScraper() {
  var webURL = "https://www.multpl.com/s-p-500-pe-ratio";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(webURL);
  var str = response.getContentText().match(/var d =([\s\S\w]+?);/);
  if (str && str.length > 0) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(str[1].trim());
    var res = obj.endLabel[0].replace(".", ",");  // If you use obj.endLabel[0] , "39.57" is returned.
    console.log(res)  // When this log is checked, "39,57" can be seen.
    return res;
  }
  return "No value.";
}
```

#### Note:

- This modified script is for your current URL of `https://www.multpl.com/s-p-500-pe-ratio`. So when you use this script for other URL, the value might not be able to be retrieved. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)
- [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: Great! It works like a charm! Would it be possible to modify this code to also use it to scrape other websites? What makes the code find the value "39.57" ? Suppose I wanted to scrape the "Mean: 15.88" , how would I modify the code to do that?

Comment: @mancoder Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to support you. But I cannot understand about `other websites`. I apologize for this. If above script cannot be directly used for your `other websites`, I think that it is required to analyze the HTML data. At that time, please post your new question as a new question. By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: I will try to clarify my follow up question. In the info that I got with my original code it gave me the PE ratio (39.57) and lots of other info. Among the info was the Mean (15.88). Your code narrowed it down to the PE ratio (39.57), which is exactly what I wanted. However, if I wanted to retrieve the Mean (15.88), how would I then modify the code?

Comment: @mancoder Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the relationship between your new questions and `other websites`. But I would like to support you. So when I could correctly understand about your new questions. I would like to try to think of the solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your new questions soon. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this again.